# Finding relative position in plus shape

Tags: geometry

[image: Example of what i need]

I am making a dithering library. To find the relative position of an absolute point `a` in a 2-dimensional plane tiled with 4 unit squares, I use `rel.x = abs.x % 4; rel.y = abs.y % 4`. This is good, and produces the expected results. But what if I am tiling the plane with plus shapes, which are 3 units? How do I find the absolute position? The tile shape is showed here, 1's are parts of the shape, and 0's are empty areas.

```
0 1 0
1 1 1 
0 1 0
```

For example, if I have point `a` resting on `x = 1, y = 1`, then the absolute position should be `x = 1, y = 1`. But if it is on, say `x = 4, y = 1`, then the absolute position should be `x = 1, y = 2`. You see, there would be another plus which's bottom is on the point `x = 1, y = 2`. How is this accomplished mathematically? Any language, pseudo code is great too. :)

Comment: i can make an image if needed :)

Comment: What do you mean by absolute position of plus shape - central coordinate of plus which point belongs to? (Yes, I realize close packing of such shapes - there are two kinds: right-right-up and right-right-down)

Comment: @MBo The absolute position would be the absolute position of a 3x3 square centered at the plus's center. And they are closely packed :)

Comment: It's worth to specify (show) your coordinate origin and tiling kind. Picture of RRD tiling to help: i.pinimg.com/236x/00/20/66/002066c83fcf2efb7acd44224403b272--patterns-to-colour-textile-patterns.jpg

Comment: Why are you mixing up *relative* and *absolute* positions? "To find the relative position of ... I use `abs.x = a.x % 4`..."

Comment: @Mbo i will do that right now, hold up 2 minutes

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Oops, typo :) Good catch my friend

Comment: @MBo the link seems to be broken - can you re-post?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog https://i.pinimg.com/originals/00/20/66/002066c83fcf2efb7acd44224403b272.png

Comment: @Mbo Here i added image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is periodicity along X and Y axes with period 5. So long switch expression might look like:

```
case y % 5 of:
     0: case x % 5 of
         0: cx = x - 1; cy = y;
         1: cx = x; cy = y + 1;
         2: cx = x; cy = y - 1;
         3: cx = x + 1; cy = y;
         4: cx = x; cy = y; 
    1:...
```

Or we can create constant array 5x5 and fill it with shifts -1, 0, 1.

```
 dx: [[-1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,-1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,-1],[0,-1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,-1,0]]
 dy: [[0,1,-1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,-1],[1,-1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,-1,0],[-1,0,0,0,1]]
```

I feel that some simple formula might exist.

Edit: simpler version:

```
 const dx0: [-1,0,0,1,0]
 const dy0: [0,1,-1,0,0]

 ixy = (x - 2 * y + 10) % 5;
 dx = dx0[ixy];   
 dy = dy0[ixy];
```

And finally **crazy one-liners** without constant arrays

```
 dx = (((11 + x - 2 * (y%5)) %  5) ^ 1 - 2) / 2    //^=xor; /2 - integer division
 dy = ((13 + x - 2 * (y%5)) %  5 - 2) / 2
```

Comment: So, there is not a straightforward way to go here? Something that could be a two liner, or the sort. I'll try this out for now, but keep answers open so others can post :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Array approach is four-liner :)

Comment: very good work. thank you so much for this, i can see you have put in a lot of effort to help me. Thank uuu :D

Comment: your the best :D

Comment: I felt, I knew! ;-)

Comment: Those one-liners OMG - did you hack the US election too? xD